# Using hotstring to create code snippets

Tags: autohotkey

I used AutoHotKey recently, where I made a hotstring which would create a piece of code so that I can increase my productivity.

Here is the hotstring:

```
::basic::#include <iostream> int main(){}
```

But the output is:

```
#include <iostream> int main()
```

This script didn't include the curly braces I reqiured.
So, I want this to run perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
::basic::#include <iostream> int main(){{}{}}
```

Comment: Thanks, now I can create code snippets easily. But where can I get the whole syntax for AutoHotKey?

Comment: Right click the AutoHotKey icon on your taskbar and select "help"

Comment: @AadhavVignesh you might want to accept this answer then, otherwise ppl will see it as unsolved. alternative syntax could be to use `SendRaw ...`